# How to force to generate first a file include in a make file

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile where I include a file (with -include titi.mak)

I would like to generate first this file and then include this file in order to benefit the variable in this file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. Put a rule in the makefile to build `titi.mak`. Then when you execute Make, Make will execute this rule and then reinvoke itself.

```
-include titi.mak

something:
    @echo the value of X is $(X)

titi.mak:
    @echo X := 5 > $@
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of solving this could be found here.

http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-include-files/